# Por que está demorando tanto o preenchimento de Dados?

Tags: java, android

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao buscar os dados na base e preencher meu objeto para manipular na tela, ele está demorando muito e vazando memória, já tentei otimizar mas não consegui.

O mais engraçado é quando fiz as primeiras consultas estava rápido, depois que começou a dar isso, alguém sabe como resolver??

```
 public List<ProdutoTO> buscarTodos() {
    // Produtos
    List<ProdutoTO> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    // Pega o cursor com todos os dados
    Cursor cursor = findAll();

    // Pega o primeiro elemento
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Produto produto = readRow(cursor);
        List<SaldoEstoque> saldos = this.saldoEstoqueDAO.getSaldoEstoque(produto, UtilGlobal.usuario);
        ProdutoTO produtoTO;
        if (saldos == null && saldos.size() == 0) {
            produtoTO = new ProdutoTO(produto, saldos.get(0));
        } else {
            produtoTO = new ProdutoTO(produto, null);
        }
        produtos.add(produtoTO);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Fecha o cursor
    cursor.close();

    // Retorna os dados
    return produtos;
}

private Produto readRow(Cursor cursor) {
    Produto produto = new Produto();
    try {
        // As colunas são recuperadas na ordem que foram selecionadas
        produto.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
        produto.setCodigo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("codigo")));
        produto.setEan(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ean")));
        produto.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
        produto.setPreco(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("preco")));
        produto.setPrecocusto(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("precocusto")));
        produto.setPrecoultimacompra(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("precoultimacompra")));
        produto.setUnidademedida(this.unidadeMedidaDAO.getUnidade(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("idunidademedida"))));
        //produto.setGrupoProduto(this.grupoProdutoDAO.getGrupoProduto(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("idhierarquia"))));
        //produto.setFamilia(this.familiaDAO.getFamilia(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("idfamilia"))));
        produto.setInativo(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("inativo")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return produto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Possível problema:**

O que pode ser é muitas requisições no seu banco de dados, primeiro você faz uma lista com todos os produtos (Cursor cursor = findAll()) e depois você faz um loop e dentro deste loop você busca os saldos do produto.

Em um cenário que você possui 100 produtos e cada produto possui 10 saldos você irá fazer 1000*(100*10)* requisições no banco(espero que você concorde comigo que é desnecessário buscar 1000 coisas no banco). E quanto mais produtos e saldos você tiver, mais lento vai demorar para terminar este 'percurso'.

**Solução:**

Particularmente prefiro a segunda opção.

1. Tente trazer todos os produtos já com todos os saldos de uma só vez.
2. Busque os produtos e na medida que você precisar precisar olhar o saldo, você busca no banco. Tenho certeza que em 100 produtos você não vai querer saber o saldo de todos os 100.